# Alias for finding a file not working in bash

Tags: bash, alias

The following alias for finding a file works in tcsh but not in bash.

```
alias ff "find . -name '*\!{*}*' -ls"
```

When I put the above line in .bashrc and then source it I get :

```
bash-3.2$ source .bashrc
bash: alias: ff: not found
bash: alias: find . -name '*\!{*}*' -ls: not found
```

Now if I define the alias but putting an equals sign just after the alias name the above error goes away but it doesn't work as expected.

```
 alias ff="find . -name '*\!{*}*' -ls"
```

Now if I source the file the previous error goes away but the `find` command doesn't work as expected.

```
 bash-3.2$ source .bashrc
 bash-3.2$ ff somefile
 find: paths must precede expression
 Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
```

Comment: What is the tcsh alias supposed to do?

Comment: @choroba  the alias will give a long listing of any file or directory names that contain the argument when a file or directory name is given as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aliases in bash can't process arguments. If you need to process an argument, use a function instead:

```
ff () { find . -name "*$1*" -ls ; }
```

Comment: What does `*$1*` expand to?

Comment: first argument to `ff` command between `**`